# how to convert gif to jpg "first frame" and upload it using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, carrierwave

I'm trying to create new version for my image uploader using carrierwave (fog), I was trying to do a condition version to check if it gif to get rid of the animation and convert to jpg but for some reason it didn't work, although the debugging is kinda tough in this.

here is my code

```html
class SourceImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  include CarrierWave::MimetypeFu

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog

  process :set_content_type

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :big_thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [600, 99999]
  end

  version :small_thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [200, 99999]
  end

  version :first_frame do
    process :remove_animation
  end

  def filename
    "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end

  protected

  def secure_token
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.hex(2))
  end

  # def is_gif?(new_file)
  #    new_file.content_type.include? 'gif' rescue false
  # end 

  def remove_animation
    if content_type == 'image/gif'
      manipulate! { |image| image.collapse! }
    end
  end
```

I was trying to user is_gif? method as condition version condition but it didn't work.

any suggestions ?

Cheers!

Comment: What didn't work exactly? What error are you getting? Why do you have `rescue false` in there?

Comment: didn't work as if i go to my s3 bucket I don't find the first frame version in there, no errors as it's also very hard to debug.
The rescue false, just in case my method (is_gif?) didn't work probably for checking the file if it gif or not but i'm not using it anymore, it didn't work.